# WPF ListBox selecting an item from mvvm doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, selection

I'm having a problem with the selecion of an item bound to the selected item of a WPF ListBox from code behind (I'm using the mvvm pattern). The weird thing is that it used to work, but now it doesn't anymore. Let me introduce the situation.

This is the ListBox inside my User Cotrol

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TrainerClassesList}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrainerClass, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

This is the property in the View Model to which the selected item is bound:

```
public TrainerClassClientEntity SelectedTrainerClass
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedTrainerClass;
            }

            set
            {
                if (EditingTrainerClass != null && !EditingTrainerClass.Equals(SelectedTrainerClass) && !EditingTrainerClass.Equals(value) && BtnSave.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Unsaved changes will be lost. Do you want to save?",
                        "Attention",
                        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxImage.Question,
                        MessageBoxResult.Yes);
                    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        BtnSave.Execute(null);
                    }
                }

                selectedTrainerClass = value;

                EditingTrainerClass = Mapper.Clone<TrainerClassClientEntity>(selectedTrainerClass);

                Raise(() => SelectedTrainerClass);
            }
        }
```

Basically what happens is that when you make changes to the textboxes of the user control etc, you don't directly change the selected item. You modify a copy of the selected item, and once you press the save button (not shown here), the changes are applied.

What I achieved days ago was a simple button that added an item to the list, and selected it. It used to work, but now it doesn't anymore. This is the action of the button (I used ICommand interface to do that, I'm not going to bother copying and pasting the whole piece of code).

```
private void AddTrainerClass()
        {
            TrainerClassClientEntity trainerClass = new TrainerClassClientEntity();
            ViewModel.TrainerClassesList.Add(trainerClass);
            ViewModel.SelectedTrainerClass = trainerClass;
        }
```

Now, I don't exactly know what I did to make it not work anymore. It does work, via debugging I learnt that it does change the property in the View Model, but it seems like it won't update the user interface.

Recently I added some validators to the textboxes, could it be the problem? Here's an example:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin ="10 5" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="EditingTrainerClass.Description" 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                    Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:StringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceValidationRule 
                    ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                    ErrorMessage="The field cannot be empty."/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Also, I think it's worth to mention that I'm using a custom WPF Theme. However, it still used to work while I was using it.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Im a bit confused about what you want to accomplish. I though SelectedItem was used for controlling which item was selected in the listbox, not for checking change. If i wanted to to put some sort of validation before overriding the previous content i would keep a different collection that the user could go back to.

Comment: How are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I just want to change the selected item pragmatically.
Yes, I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: have you tried removing the validation then, if you suspect this might be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a method that you say is supposed to *apply the changes* [to the selected item], but unless you have omitted some code from this method, it doesn't appear to apply any changes... surely you need to copy the values from the current selected item to the new one? Either something like this:

```
private void AddTrainerClass()
{
    TrainerClassClientEntity trainerClass = new TrainerClassClientEntity(
        ViewModel.SelectedTrainerClass);
    ViewModel.TrainerClassesList.Add(trainerClass);
    ViewModel.SelectedTrainerClass = trainerClass;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
private void AddTrainerClass()
{
    TrainerClassClientEntity trainerClass = new TrainerClassClientEntity();
    trainerClass.CopyValuesFrom(ViewModel.SelectedTrainerClass);
    ViewModel.TrainerClassesList.Add(trainerClass);
    ViewModel.SelectedTrainerClass = trainerClass;
}
```